# Direct3D window opens to white screen

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d, directx-9

In the source code I'm using my program is opening a window which displays a white screen and immediately becomes unresponsive. Please help me find the issue with my code.

Windows.cpp

```
#include "DirectX.h"

using namespace std;
bool gameover = false;

//Windows event handler
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        gameover = true;
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

//Windows entry point
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    //initializes window settings
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainWindowClass";
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //create a new window
    HWND window = CreateWindow(L"MainWindowClass", APPTITLE,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        SCREENW, SCREENH, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (window == 0) return 0;

    //display the window
    ShowWindow(window, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(window);

    //initialize the game
    if (!Game_Init(window)) return 0;

    //main message loop
    MSG message;
    while (!gameover) {
        if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }

        //process game loop
        Game_Run(window);
    }

    //shutdown game
    Game_End();
    return message.wParam;
}
```

DirectX.cpp
I assume this is where the problem is happening

```
bool Direct3D_Init(HWND window, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) 
{
    //initialize Direct3D
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if (!d3d) return false;

    //set Direct3D presentation parameters
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = !fullscreen;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = window;

    //create Direct3D device
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, window,
        D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dpp, &d3ddev);
    if (!d3ddev) return false;

    //get a pointer to the back buffer surface
    d3ddev->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &backbuffer);

    //create sprite object
    D3DXCreateSprite(d3ddev, &spriteobj);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: `CreateDevice()`, `GetBackBuffer()`, and `D3DXCreateSprite()` all return an HRESULT that you are throwing away.. are you sure that they aren't giving you more information? Where are you drawing the sprite onto the surface? Your message pump doesn't include code to allow for checking a keystroke or mouse click for exit, so it makes sense that all input is being ignored.

Comment: How is `Direct3D_Init` even being called? You aren't including all of the relevant code.

Comment: Direct3D_Init is being called from Game_Init(), thats all Game_Init() does.

Comment: If you were using Direct3D 11, I'd strongly recommend starting with the [Direct3D Win32 Game template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) and the DirectX Tool Kit [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) which address setting up a render window, device, and swap chain in some detail. Direct3D 9 is over a decade old at this point, and D3DX9 (i.e. ``D3DXCreateSprite``) is deprecated along with the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

My Game project just have the same issue. The Game was built success but when I start it. It show white screen.
I've just fixed this error. If you have a GPU (NVidia or ...) you should disable it. Like I did in this image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiQE0.jpg)

Comment: The question you are answering to is in style of "I have a problem, please fix it for me." I don't think it deserves any response, especially the kind that is highly subjective.